# HMM 3-state phone model and transition probability

Tags: speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I read this question
[3-state phone model in Hidden Markov Model (HMM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112608/3-state-phone-model-in-hidden-markov-model-hmm)

and I understood what 3-state means, but still don't understand why transition matrix made with (state+2)*(state+2) matrix.

This is what I got. I have datas about 21 phones.

```
    #define N_STATE     3
    #define N_PDF       10
    #define N_DIMENSION 39

    typedef struct {
      float weight;
      float mean[N_DIMENSION];
      float var[N_DIMENSION];
    } pdfType;

    typedef struct {
      pdfType pdf[N_PDF];
    } stateType;

    typedef struct {
      char *name;
      float tp[N_STATE+2][N_STATE+2];
      stateType state[N_STATE];
    } hmmType;

    hmmType phones[] = {
      { "f", // HMM
        { // transition probability
  { 0.000000e+000, 1.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000 },
  { 0.000000e+000, 8.519424e-001, 1.480576e-001, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000 },
  { 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 7.039050e-001, 2.960950e-001, 0.000000e+000 },
  { 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 5.744837e-001, 4.255163e-001 },
  { 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000, 0.000000e+000 }
},
{
  {{// state 1
    { // pdf 1
      8.379531e-002,
      { -1.100132e+001, -1.507629e+000, 5.286411e+000, 5.901514e+000, 1.883457e+000, 2.984173e-001, -2.267562e+000, -1.421130e+000, -2.029700e+000, -8.125367e-001, -5.360930e-001, -2.711542e+000, 5.227489e+001, -5.095788e+000, -1.696621e+000, -7.312185e-001, 1.086982e+000, 1.082798e+000, 6.809577e-001, 9.642316e-001, 1.288318e+000, 2.270788e+000, 9.616309e-001, 3.370467e-001, 5.757959e-001, -9.360286e-001, 5.963516e-001, -5.518724e-001, -6.216772e-001, -1.133040e+000, -1.055158e+000, -2.527018e-001, -5.493749e-001, -8.677255e-002, -4.314532e-001, 4.211203e-002, 1.891589e-001, -1.295372e-001, 2.562751e-001 },
      { 2.583579e+001, 1.714888e+001, 1.768794e+001, 1.732637e+001, 1.677207e+001, 2.317034e+001, 1.957299e+001, 1.885118e+001, 1.923330e+001, 1.748584e+001, 1.841182e+001, 1.546110e+001, 2.689937e+001, 2.333710e+000, 2.154598e+000, 5.479347e+000, 5.589773e+000, 4.148128e+000, 3.470205e+000, 3.396770e+000, 3.723966e+000, 4.144585e+000, 3.967475e+000, 3.933262e+000, 2.597734e+000, 1.499691e+000, 5.463322e-001, 4.699343e-001, 6.001114e-001, 6.452432e-001, 5.413819e-001, 6.319258e-001, 6.051217e-001, 6.727058e-001, 7.212463e-001, 7.243521e-001, 6.977258e-001, 5.134848e-001, 2.294584e-001 }
    ...
```

I know there is transition matrix in structure hmmType.

1) But why [N_STATE+2][N_STATE+2] not [N_STATE][N_STATE]?

2) Does it mean a transition probability from one phone to another phone? Then how can I use it to know transition probability from 'f' to 't'?

3) or just from one state to other state in same phone?

4) and If that is right, how can I get transition probability from one phone to another phone?(ex 'f' -> 't') As I understood If I want to do speech recognition with Viterbi algorithm, I need transition probabilities from a phone to other phone, but I'm not even sure this data contains it or not. Should I train it from datas?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) But why [N_STATE+2][N_STATE+2] not [N_STATE][N_STATE]?

The programmer who wrote this code decided to write like that but overall it has not the most straightforward approach, he could simply declare N_STATE as 5.

> 2) Does it mean a transition probability from one phone to another phone? Then how can I use it to know transition probability from 'f' to 't'?

This transition probability is encoded in dictionary or in the language model, not in the acoustic model.

> 3) or just from one state to other state in same phone?

Yes

> 4) and If that is right, how can I get transition probability from one phone to another phone?(ex 'f' -> 't') As I understood If I want to do speech recognition with Viterbi algorithm, I need transition probabilities from a phone to other phone, but I'm not even sure this data contains it or not. Should I train it from datas?

You can train it from data, that is frequently referred as phonetic bigram language model and used in TIMIT evaluations.